# How to remove rows that has duplicate values on part of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating script that reads xlsx file to pandas dataframe and appends new rows to it. However, my problem is that I don't want to add dublicates that have same values in the first four columns (contains 5 columns overall). The fifth column value can be anything, but based on dublicates on these four columns I would like to delete the whole row.

My code is fully functional apart from this. I could do this by looping the dataframe, but I believe that there is smarter way to do this.

Example of data in below. How can I delete the last row, when it has same four columns as the row 4 but different 5th column?

```
    Category Year Week Price Amount
0   1        2019 27   2     1
1   1        2019 28   3     2
2   1        2019 29   4     3
3   2        2019 29   4     4
4   3        2019 30   5     3
5   3        2019 30   5     4
```

Part of the code:

```
# Append new rows to dataframe
file_df = file_df.append(new_rows, sort=False, ignore_index=True)

# Delete dublicate rows
combined_df = combined_df.drop_duplicates()
```

This code now removes only the rows with exactly same column values. Anyway, I could not find smart solution for removing such duplicates. Please correct me, if the question is not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [`pd.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and set `subset` column on which you want to compare values

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Category' ,'Year', 'Week' ,'Price'],inplace=True)
```